# Traefik and WildCard Certificates Issue By Third party

Tags: traefik

I have traefik set up and running, but experiencing issues with https, (wildcard certificate). Im able to get a redirect from 80 to 443 but nothing will load. I donot see much information in the logs and they have been set to debug level

Checked the permissions for the cert and set logs to debug
0644 on crt and 0600 on key

Tarefik TOML

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/traefik/certs/server.crt"
      keyFile = "/etc/traefik/certs/server.key"
```

Docker Compose

```
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /home/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/traefik/certs:/etc/traefik/certs
    networks:
      - traefik-net
```

Sample NGINX server being run

```
 nginx-docker:
    image: nginx:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:<hostname>.eogresources.com"
    networks:
      - traefik-net
```

Comment: `nothing will load` - could you please be more specific than that. Also, what do you expect to load? Does your expected configuration matches the one, that the debug logs produces?

Comment: Im just running an nginx server. I can see the redirect from 80 to 443 but the page will not load when i add the cert configurations. The debug logs dont really show much when i try connecting to the page. Sample compose file config for NGINX added above. I can get to it and see the connection being routed through traefik when i do not enable SSL.

Comment: Webpage returns : Unable to connect" No cert information visible through we-browser. Page should return a simple NGINX (default page)

Comment: You did no answer this: "Does your expected configuration matches the one, that the debug logs produces?", you just repeated that you debug logs don't show much. Also, what port do you think your browser unable to connect to?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong , youre asking if the config file is set up correctly to show the debug logs? Yes they are. Once i remove the SSL configs i can actually see the proper logs (and they are verbose ). Which makes me think that the connection is not making it properly to traefik or getting terminated while being routed. I see the url change http to https, whcih tells me that the redirect works but i get nothing beyond that point

Toml Config: 
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

I have two dummy services one on 80 and the other on 8066

Comment: `you're asking if the config file is set up correctly to show the debug logs` - no. I'm asking if the configuration you configured and expect to see show up in the debug logs correctly. I've see many cases, when people _thought_ that they configured something but that's not what the traefik thought. So best way to check is to examine the log and see if the configuration matches the expectation. Often it is not.

Comment: `have two dummy services one on 80 and the other on 8066` So you are directing your browser to connect on port 80 and it does not connect and you direct your browser to connect on port 8066 and it does not connect, is this right?

Comment: Yes i actually change the certificate permissions to see if it actually shows the failure; and it does. When i chnage it back to what i expect to be correct , i see in the logs that the system is loading the wildcard cert with the domain name and adding TLS to the URLs i have listed.
level=debug msg="Add certificate for domains ,<DOMAINNAME>
level=debug msg="Adding TLSClientHeaders middleware for frontend frontend-Host-<FQDN>

Comment: That is correct i have two services running , which without the certificate and redirect work just fine. I tried removing the redirect , and only kept the cert on 443, doesnt seem to help

Comment: I figured out my mistake. I just needed to add `443:443` to my port in docker-compose file for traefik, no wonder i couldnt see the connection failure logs when i was trying to connect. Silly mistake. The rest of the configurations are all good.
Thanks @Andrew Savinykh, i guess i just needed to look at this with fresh eyes.

Comment: Yep. That's why I was asking about ports - my next question was going to be how does traefik know about that ;)

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance, got my brain cells working now.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing 443 on traefik resolved my issue. Added additional port docker-compose file, change reflected below. Silly mistake. Also added the network in compose file

```
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /home/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/traefik/certs:/etc/traefik/certs
    networks:
      - traefik-net  

networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: "overlay"
```